# RetCode 401 error

Tags: php, yii

I am getting this error recently after login

{"RetCode":401,"data":[],"message":"Unautherized user[hashmissing]."}.

I am using php yii framework. This error getting recently only before its working fine. The same code is working on other systems.

Need to do any internet setting or any configuration on my php file.

Thanks in Advance,
Raja M

Comment: I will suppose what it is _not_ Yii error. Yii have not such error description. So, it may be error of some of the modules you included, or your own handmade code.

Comment: I thought it's not related to any code issue becz the same code is working on others machine. This is related to some settings issues with yii/php/xamp/internet settings